# CSS gradients with multiple stops and borders

Tags: css, css-gradients

I am looking to make a css equivalent to the picture below. I am using multiple stops, but am having a hard time getting a hard stop `solid 2px white` border. If I add it, it looks like it is a gradient and not a hard edge. Any help would be great, thanks!

[image]

```css
.stripes {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3f2919 0%, #3f2919 6%, #ffffff 6%, #ffffff 7%, #68adc6 7%, #68adc6 20%, #875e3b 20%, #875e3b 40%, #86979b 40%, #86979b 45%, #83a450 45%, #83a450 70%, #75753a 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to insert also the white color into the gradient colors:

```css
.stripes {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
    #3f2919 0%, #3f2919 6%, 
    #ffffff  calc(6%  + 2px), #68adc6  calc(6% +  2px), #68adc6 20%, 
    #ffffff  calc(20% + 2px), #875e3b  calc(20% + 2px), #875e3b 40%,     
    #ffffff  calc(40% + 2px), #86979b  calc(40% + 2px), #86979b 45%,
    #ffffff  calc(45% + 2px), #83a450  calc(45% + 2px), #83a450 70%, 
    #ffffff  calc(70% + 2px), #75753a  calc(70% + 2px), #75753a );
}
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>
```

make it sharper

```css
.stripes {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
    #3f2919 0%, #3f2919 6%, 
    #ffffff  6%,#ffffff  calc(6%  + 2px), #68adc6  calc(6% +  2px), #68adc6 20%, 
    #ffffff 20%,#ffffff  calc(20% + 2px), #875e3b  calc(20% + 2px), #875e3b 40%,     
    #ffffff 40%,#ffffff  calc(40% + 2px), #86979b  calc(40% + 2px), #86979b 45%,
    #ffffff 45%,#ffffff  calc(45% + 2px), #83a450  calc(45% + 2px), #83a450 70%, 
    #ffffff 70%,#ffffff  calc(70% + 2px), #75753a  calc(70% + 2px), #75753a );
}
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>
```

viewed from chrome:
[image: chrome screenshot]

Comment: The white lines still appear to be blurry, atleast in chrome? Anyway to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

that's most likely due to the percentage units and the way this is handled by browsers and OSes (rounding vs. anti-aliasing etc.). If you really want only 2px thin white stripes, it might be better to use strict pixel values in the gradient.

Comment: right, I get what you are saying, but the graph will be used for an unknown width i.e (100%)

Comment: if you don't need the *complete* graph to appear (but can live with a little bit of it being cut off to the right or at both sides), you could create 3 (or more) different sizes with fixed pixed values, put those in media queries to apply them at different viewport sizes, use background-size 100% and let the overflowing part be cut off (?)